# Facebook API example code has errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

I've got this example straight off facebook api docs and I keep getting `Reference Error: FB is not defined` in both firefox and IE10.

I do not understand why FB is not defined when I used their example code? Is this just a security exception because I'm running this locally or is there really something wrong with the FB docs code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FB Login Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '(my app id)',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function facebookLogin(){
            FB.login(function(response){
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information');
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });

                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
    <a href="javascript:facebookLogin();">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because of this line, and the fact you are using local pages:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

When urls do not provide the protocol the browser will use whatever protocol the browser is currently viewing. Since you are using this from a local source the used link will be

```
file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js
```

If you want to use it from a local source you need to add the protocol to the url

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```